# Vuex - Load data from API on first getter call and then load from state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a `Vuex` instance which loads data from `API`. The first time I access the store it should load the data from API, and when I access it again it should return the loaded data from the `store.empresas`. This is how my Vuex module looks like:

```
import Empresas from '@/api/empresas'
import moment from 'moment'

export default {
  state: {
    loaded: false,
    lastLoadedDate: null,
    empresas: []
  },

  getters: {
    empresas: state => {
      if (!state.loaded || moment().diff(state.lastLoadedDate, 'minutes') > 30) {
        //Was not loaded yet or was loaded more than 30 minutes ago,
        //Sould load from api -> actions.carregarEmpresas()
        //Don't know how to proceed here
      } else {
        //Already loaded
        return state.empresas
      }
    }
  },

  mutations: {
    setEmpresas (state, payload) {
      state.loaded = true
      state.lastLoadedDate = moment()
      state.empresas = payload
    }
  },

  actions: {
    carregarEmpresas ({ commit }) {
      Empresas.listar()
        .then(({ data }) => {
          commit('setEmpresas', data.empresas)
        })
    }
  }
}
```

The reason I need this is that I will need to access `empresas` in multiple files in my application, and I don't want to make an API call every time.

However, I don't know how to implement it inside the getter. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2):

This might be a duplicate of this post: [Can I do dispatch from getters in Vuex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678690/can-i-do-dispatch-from-getters-in-vuex). Check if the second answer helps you.

Basically, you shouldn't call actions from you getters. I would recommend you call the action at the initial load of the app. Then you will just use the getter without the conditional.